# Unbounded memory growth with a repeatForever SKAction

Tags: ios, memory-management, sprite-kit, skaction

I am building a SpriteKit iOS game, with a single view (having an admob subview, likely unrelated to this issue) and a single scene that has game play as well as menu buttons managed within the same single scene.

I am noticing unbounded memory growth even when the game is just showing the menu (for the first time) - the only thing that is moving there is a pulsating SKAction to pulse the Play button.

The relevant code is shown below:

```
// GameScene.m
@interface GameScene ()
@property(nonatomic, strong)SKAction *pulseAction;
@end

@implementation GameScene
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
     SKAction *shrinkAction = [SKAction scaleBy:0.8 duration:0.4];
     SKAction *growAction = [SKAction scaleBy:1.25 duration:0.4];
    _pulseAction = [SKAction sequence:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:shrinkAction, growAction, nil]];
}

-(void)showGameOverMenu {
  [PlayButtonCircleShapeNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:_pulseAction]];
}
@end
```

I cannot see any other part of the code having any implication, except that I preload the textures (I have tried using local variables as well as ivars for the textures as suggested in other threads, but doesn't seem to impact either way). Any thoughts?

Thanks
Anand

Comment: How fast does the memory grow? Is it a slow trickle?

Comment: how did you determine the memory growth? Check with Instruments which objects are alive, which are created new but not deallocated, whether there are any leaks.

Comment: @Theis: The memory grows slowly but more or less steadily, about 1 MB every 4 seconds.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: There are no leaks, and the memory allocations are happening in system libraries - GLLibrary, QuartzCore, IOSurface, IOAccelerator and of course, in SpriteKit. Nothing in my code. The strange thing is that memory allocations in the Allocations List stopped at about 58 seconds, but in the Statistics View, the heap grows steadily even way beyond - (am at 8 minutes now).

Comment: BTW, I also disabled admob (removed its subview entirely) to eliminate it as the cause of the memory growth.

Comment: I have experienced the same with SpriteKit projects, at some point though it levels out. I'm pretty sure it has to do with spritekit retaining some things till its sure it won't be reused.